# Assign localparam with concatenation satement?

Tags: verilog

Here's what I'm trying to do . . .

```
localparam nine1 = {3{4'b0000}, 4'b1001};
localparam nine2 = {2{4'b0000}, 2{nine1}};
```

Is it possible to assign a `localparam` with a concat satement and then use that `localparam` in another `localparam` assignment? It seems like it would work, but I might have fuddled something up. This is not system verilog by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the error was that I wasn't wrapping my `replication statements` in `{}` inside the `concatenation`.

```
localparam nine1 = {{3{4'b0000}}, 4'b1001};
localparam nine2 = {{2{4'b0000}}, {2{nine1}}};
```

Subtle, but important.